# Why has my reputation gone away after my question has been removed

Tags: support, reputation, deleted-questions

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How does deleting work? What can cause a post to be deleted, and what does that actually mean?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5221/how-does-deleting-work-what-can-cause-a-post-to-be-deleted-and-what-does-that)

Yesterday I answered [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14003064/what-does-this-mean-parse-error-syntax-error-unexpected-t-string-expecting-t/14003086). I had 5 upvotes. Then question was closed, now it is completely removed and I've lost 50 rep. I dont understand this behavior... why the question has been removed and what is the a way to recover the rep?

Comment: The question was removed because it was a terrible question, and no you can't get the reputation back.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The question seems to be from a person fiddling with web pages without knowing what she is doing (as we can see from the comments to the other answer).

Being a somewhat silly editing error, rather that a real programming problem, it is unlikely that the question will help others later. So it was removed.

Unfortunately, when the question is deleted, so is your answer. And unless the post has been open for several months, and thus shown *some* value, the rep is gone too.

Answer (score 1):

The [FAQ](https://stackoverflow.com/faq#deletion) reports when questions are deleted.

> Questions that are extremely off topic, or of very low quality, may be removed at the discretion of the community and moderators.
>
> Over time, closed questions that are not useful as signpoints to other questions may also be removed, as well as questions which have no significant activity over a very long period after being asked. For additional guidance, see [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask).

You lose the reputation you gained from answers when the answer is deleted, or the question answered by your question is deleted, or your question is deleted. You retain the reputation only when the question is X days old.

Comment: 60 days old, I don't think views come into play when retaining rep. It has to have a score of 3 or higher too.

Comment: It could be my memory is failing me. `:)`

Comment: I found the duped FAQ post, see the comment on the OP.

Comment: Oh right, it was the score! `:)`